# How to find out if a random term is in the last 5 values of a dictionary?

Tags: python

I'm building a Twitter bot and I use a random query term.  I save the date and query term to a text file.  I would like to check if the current query term is in the last 5 values of my memory dictionary.

I read the .txt file, split into key and values of a dictionary and I'm not sure what to do next.  In psuedo code, I'd like to say query = d.values(last value in dictionary : or in the last 5 values) and then I'd pick a new query.

2019-09-23,computerscience
2019-09-24,python
2019-09-25,computerprogrammer
2019-09-26,computerscience
2019-09-27,AI
2019-09-28,machinelearning
2019-09-29,neuralnetworks
2019-09-30,computerscience

```py
    d = {}
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            (key, val) = line.split(",")
            val = val[:-1]
            d[key] = val
```

If I print(d.values()) it gives me all the values like I want which is great.  Now I want to check what the last 5 values are.  I'm using python 3.7 so the dictionary should be an ordered dict by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
last_five = list(d.values())[-5:]
def check_query(queryterm):     
    if queryterm in last_five:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Thank you!  It was the syntax of creating the list that was messing me up.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, but from your last sentence, I infer you may want something like this:

```
d = {}
with open(file_name) as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.split(",")
        val = val[:-1]
        d[key] = val
print(list(d.values())[-5:])
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I guess just the syntax of creating the list and where to put the -5 got me.